# number of additional unique samples from a distribution?

Tags: probability, sampling

after drawing N times from distribution P (over a large but discrete set of things), we have K unique things.

If we draw N+M times, how many unique things will we have, in expectation?

make assumptions on the kinds of distribution of P as needed to solve the problem, for me P is a large language model, and the "unique things" are samples from the large language model.

Comment: The expectation isn’t well-defined without a prior for the possible distributions.